# gnuplot: rotate line title and set offset

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot hs-diagram from csv files.

To plot lines I use

```
plot 'it175.csv' using 7:6 with lines lc rgb 'green' title '175K' at begin, \
'ib50.csv' using 7:6 with lines lc rgb 'red' title '50MPa' at end
```

It gives nice isotherm titles,

[image]

but worse isobaric

[image]

How can I rotate line titles and set offset to the end of the line using 'title "title" at end' without using labels, because there are over 430 lines, and it is very difficult to adjust label coordinates for each line by hand

Comment: So, for each line you have a separate file? Roughly how many datapoints? How many files? What is the `862` in the second image, a third type of label?

Comment: @theozh About 620 points for each line, 568 files (lines).
862 - density in kg/m3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize: you want to print the key/legend/title at the end of the curve rotated by a suitable angle.

If you check `help plot title` and although it is linked to `help key` for further parameters, I couldn't find any statement about rotated keys (gnuplot 5.4.1).
So, it looks like you have to rotate them yourself, at least, with some effort you can do it automatically.

- there is the plotting style `with labels` which has variable rotation (check `help labels`)
- the rotation angle of the text should be equal to the angle of the last segment of the curve
- you need to determine the angle of the last segment of each curve, however, you cannot simply take the coordinates of your plot, but you need to take the "pixel coordinates" of the screen to get the proper "visual" angle.

What the following script does:

- generates input files for illustration, like your files which contain the value of the labels already in the filename
- get a list of all files obeying a certain pattern, e.g. `it*.dat`
- create a "preliminary" plot in order to get the relationships between plot coordinates and pixel coordinates via the gnuplot variables `GPVAL_...` which you only get after plotting.
- plot your data again with lines and labels and at the same time extract the "visual" angle of the last segment of each curve and rotate the label (key/title) accordingly.

I hope you can follow the script below and adapt it to your data. If you need more explanations, let me know. Maybe there is a simpler solution which I am currently not aware of.

**Script:**

```
### rotate title at end of curve
reset session

# create some test data files
do for [t=0:5] {
    set print sprintf("it%d.dat",t*5+370)
        do for [x=0:100:5] {
            print sprintf("%g %g",x,(t/3.+0.2)*x**2+t*2000)
        }
    set print
}
do for [t=0:6] {
    set print sprintf("ib%d.dat",t*5+20)
        do for [x=0:100:5] {
            print sprintf("%g %g",x*(t+1)/10.,x**3/35.)
        }
    set print
}

# get a file list

GetFileList(path,expr) = GPVAL_SYSNAME[1:7] eq "Windows" ? \
                         sprintf('dir /b "%s%s"', path, expr) : \
                         sprintf('ls "%s%s"',     path, expr)     # Linux/MacOS
FILES_it = system(GetFileList('','it*.dat'))
FILES_ib = system(GetFileList('','ib*.dat'))

set key noautotitle
set offset 0, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, 0

# plot to get the GPVAL_ ... values
plot for [FILE in FILES_it] FILE u 1:2 w l lc "red", \
     for [FILE in FILES_ib] FILE u 1:2 w l lc "green"

# store GPVAL parameters after plot in variables
txmin = GPVAL_TERM_XMIN; txmax = GPVAL_TERM_XMAX; tymin = GPVAL_TERM_YMIN; tymax = GPVAL_TERM_YMAX
xmin  = GPVAL_X_MIN;     xmax  = GPVAL_X_MAX;     ymin  = GPVAL_Y_MIN;     ymax  = GPVAL_Y_MAX

# x,y to pix and pix to x,y coordinate conversion
XtoPix(x)    = txmin + real(x-xmin)    *(txmax-txmin)/( xmax- xmin)
YtoPix(y)    = tymin + real(y-ymin)    *(tymax-tymin)/( ymax- ymin)

# angle from -180° to +180°
set angle degrees
Angle(x0,y0,x1,y1) = (_dx=x1-x0, _dy=y1-y0, _L=sqrt(_dx**2 + _dy**2), _L==0 ? NaN : \
                     (_dy>=0 ? acos(_dx/_L) : -acos(_dx/_L) ))
# angle for screen coordinates
AngleScr(x0,y0,x1,y1) = Angle(XtoPix(x0),YtoPix(y0),XtoPix(x1),YtoPix(y1))

myLabel(fname,unit) = sprintf(" %s %s",fname[3:strstrt(fname,'.')-1],unit)   # extract number from filename

plot for [FILE in FILES_it] FILE u (last=$0,$1):2 w l lc "red", \
     for [FILE in FILES_it] x1=y1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=$1,$0==1?x1:NaN):(y0=y1,y1=$2,$0==1?y1:NaN):\
         (myLabel(FILE,"K")):(AngleScr(x0,y0,x1,y1)) every ::last-1::last w labels rotate var left font ",11", \
     for [FILE in FILES_ib] FILE u (last=$0,$1):2 w l lc "green", \
     for [FILE in FILES_ib] x1=y1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=$1,$0==1?x1:NaN):(y0=y1,y1=$2,$0==1?y1:NaN):\
         (myLabel(FILE,"MPa")):(AngleScr(x0,y0,x1,y1)) every ::last-1::last w labels rotate var left font ",11"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: argh! the constructs `last=$0` and `every ::last-1::last` in the plotting loops assume that all files have the same number of lines, which might not be true in the general case. I will think about it.

Comment: It plot lines, but there is no labels.
I plot it with 'svg terminal'. And in linux.
Anyway - thanks

Comment: and...it won't work with xrange. "line 36: all points y value undefined!". gnuplot 5.4.3

Comment: If it is difficult to do, it is enough to rotate all labels by just 45 degrees

Comment: @MPEI_stud what do you mean with "won't work with xrange"? I assume *your* line 36 is the plot command. So you added a line `set xrange[]`. What xrange do you set? What x-range do your datafiles have?